# API from proxy not working after deploying on netlify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, netlify

I am using api which is deployed in heroku to my react app. To fix the cors error, I add proxy in package.json as

```
"proxy":"https://mobtech.herokuapp.com"
```

While calling api , i do it like this

```
 const res = await axios.get('/api/user')
```

So, doing such works fine on development but not after deploying to netlify. I read official docs from netlify docs [click](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/) but it doesnot lighten my mind. Can someone help me by giving example?

Comment: Proxy doesn't work in production

Comment: It works on heroku. So what could be solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maybe late but here how it is done. Netlify should have special file in your root directory called  __redirect and you can define your proxy there like

```
/api/* https://yourapi.domain.com/:splat 200
/* /index.html 200
```

Then you can call your api like this

```
const res = fetch('/api/user')   //equivalent to https://yourapi.domain.com/user
```

Hope this helped

Comment: Hey Saral, I know it's not place to ask, but can we connect? I have some questions related to netlify. Please ?

Comment: Netlify has very good support team and they reply every your question in a quick time. I am not in netlify support team. So you can consider asking there https://answers.netlify.com/

Answer (score 0):

If your @Heroku endpoint is setup this way,
heroku api is: [enter link description here](https://domain.herokuapp.com)
and fetching  api like
const fetch= await axios.get(/api/users)

Add _redirects file in public folder of react app
and write this way

/api/* https://domain.herokuapp.com/api/:splat 200 /* /index.html 200

Answer (score 0):

Adding the above-mentioned lines in `_redirects` file helps, but just a heads up in this situation. Suppose you have an API call written from your React app to your Express server this way,

```
fetch("/api/v1/items", {method: "POST"})
.then(response => response.json()).
then(res=> console.log(res))
.catch(error => {console.log(error)});
```

which means your endpoint in Express starts with the term `/api`.

In this situation make sure that your `_redirect` file looks something like this,

```
/api/* https://yoia-apis.onrender.com/api/:splat 200
/* /index.html 200
```

There should be an extra term `/api` before `:splat` as the `:splat` entertains those entities represented by `*`, i.e. components of routes that come after `api/`, in these situations.