# Heroku Deploy Vite Static App Won't Connect to API with Axios Using a Proxy

Tags: vue.js, heroku, axios, proxy, vite

I think this problem follows this one on netlify [API from proxy not working after deploying on netlify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67986822/api-from-proxy-not-working-after-deploying-on-netlify)

I am setting up a Vite app and making an axios api request in my app component

```
getSuggestionList(street, zip, city) {
        this.axios.get('/1.0/address/find?country=at&zip=' + zip + '&city=' + city + '&street-address=' + street + '&street-number=&offset=1&limit=100', {
            auth: {
                username: '7166-631A-5394-4C03-9106-0A93-C433-2613',
                password: ''
            }
        })
```

Now, for development I configured a proxy in server

in vite.config.js

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/1.0/address': 'http://api.opendata.host/'
    }
  },
  proxy: {
    '/1.0/address': {
      target: 'http://api.opendata.host/',
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,      
      ws: true,
    }
  }
});
```

Following this guide

https://rubenr.dev/en/cors-vite-vue/

I understand this does not transfer to production, so I also tried the proxy part. I don't get a response, just like described in the netlify guide.

From Heroku docs

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static

I have the basic setup without proxies (leading to the initial, no-response behavior)

in static.json:

```
{
    "root": "./dist",
    "clean_urls": true,
    "routes": {
      "/**": "index.html"
    },
    "proxies": {
        "/1.0/address": {
            "origin": "http://api.opendata.host/"
        }
    }
  }
```

And  when I add proxies I get a 404 not found. When I change up the spelling: no response again, so it seems to be making a connection with the proxies configuration. But why not they way it works locally? Does anyone see my error here or having something for me to try?

Answer (score 0):

I found it: for anyone else having trouble with this kind of deployment on Heroku -- the mountpoint "/1.0/address" in static.json seems to be replaced resulting in the 404 not found.

For production I added a prefix /api in my axios call, something like

```
var apiPath = '/1.0/address/find?country=at&zip=' + zip + '&city=' + city + '&street-address=' + street + '&street-number=&offset=1&limit=100'
        var prodMountpoint = '/api' // /api/
        if (import.meta.env.PROD) {
            apiPath = prodMountpoint + apiPath
        }
```

This results in a correct api call: "/api" is replaced with the proxied host, if I understand correctly. For development, the vite.config.js does its work as before.